# Mathematica doesn't italicise a function's argument in the function's body if it appears in the denominator and the denominator is edited. A bug?

Tags: bugs, syntax-highlighting, input

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and persisting through 10.1.0 or later**

---

I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2 for Mac. On a fresh kernel, I type this:

[image: some simple fraction]

`a` is not italicised after the denominator is edited. Is this a bug in 10.0.2?

Comment: Yes, bug, report it.  I've reported this at least twice already and it's been there since 10.0.0.

Comment: I noticed this too but I did not bother to find as minimal an example.  +1 for that.

Comment: @Szabolcs I modified your header to allow searching for "bug introduced in 10.0.0"

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I will report it as well.

Comment: We are aware of this issue in Mathematica 10.0 and onwards.